# Find euler number,eccentricity etc. with Opencv Moments function

Tags: image, opencv, processing, shapes

I need to calculate some properties such as

- entropy
- Solidity
- EulerNumber
- Eccentricity
- AreaOverPerimeter
- Perimeter
- equivalentDiameter
- Filled Area

Is there any code that can calculate these properties with opencv moments function? I believe that it exists, but I couldn't find any code in C++ which calculates them.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you have some contour and want to calculate those values. 
The quickest method of calculating those above properties is convert normal contour into "Extremal Region (ER)".

```
§ MSERsToERStats()
void cv::text::MSERsToERStats   (   InputArray  image,
std::vector< std::vector< Point > > &   contours,
std::vector< std::vector< ERStat > > &  regions 
)
```

The ER struct is defined at:
    http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/d20/structcv_1_1text_1_1ERStat.html 
As you can see, they have all those properties. Also, you need text modules to use it.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/Vision_lecture/node36.html
Check this site . It defines many paramenters to process segmented images

Comment: This is not an answer. Add  as comment